# AWS cost explorer boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Need some information on the boto3. I am trying to the fetch the cost explorer as per the link (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ce.html#client)

But I get an error saying there is no service called CE. 
I am trying from lambda.

```
import boto3
clt = boto3.client('ce')
print clt
```

Error:

> module initialization error: Unknown service: 'ce'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, athena, autoscaling, batch, budgets, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, ...........

Can anyone help on the getting this service executing successfully or any other alternative way to get cost explorer via api.

Answer (score 1):

try updating also botocore

```
 pip install -U botocore
```

I've had the same problem with a recently installed boto3 an the botocore update resolved the issue, i have now botocore-1.8.0

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Cost Explorer was just released. In the CLI you need version 1.11.190 or newer which was released yesterday. I do not see an update to boto3 yet that supports Cost Explorer. If you directly use botocore, version 1.7.48 supports Cost Explorer.

[Botocore Cost Explorer](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ce.html)

Comment: I tried the below code, stil the same.

import botocore.session
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('ce')
print client

Still doesn't work. Same error
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'ce'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, athena, autoscaling, batch, budgets, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito-iden..........

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, that worked. However, I am unable to filter Region wise, Is there a possibility to fix that using the filter

Comment: Praveen, Create a new question on filters and post your code. One of us will know the solution.